# Google Analytics Advanced Segments message: "Reached the maximum number (20) of OR conditions in the above AND block"

Tags: google-analytics

In order to segment URLs according to a specific site category, I created a segment as in the attached image, which works, but I also want to include in the segment individual posts that don't have /my-category/ in their paths.

[image]

I then added a bunch of OR filters as [Landing Page] [Contains] [Post URL] and that works as well, but I can only add 20 until I get the msg 'Reached the maximum number (20) of OR conditions in the above AND block'. I'm not sure where the AND comes in (I get each filter is considered an AND?) but the segment stops displaying data when I add a second filter to continue the OR landing page URLs.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried stringing all your additional URL patterns into a single regex? e.g. [Landing Page][matches regex][(page1|page-2|page_three)]

Comment: @vinoaj That worked, thanks. A small field like that would be a bit awkward with 1000 URLs, but yup, that did the trick :)

Comment: Great! Your long-term option is to use custom dimensions and set a dimension to capture page type on each page. You can then easily filter by that dimension in future.

Comment: @vinoaj Thanks. While segments give me retroactive, I don't know if they allow me to compare against other segments, as I believe I'd be able to with groups. My end goal is to be able to look at percentages of organic landing page traffic coming from each group/segment. I don't mean to open a whole new can of worms in the comments, so I may start a new thread :D